# jquery form validation issue

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("steam_id", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^STEAM_0:(0|1):[0-9]{1}[0-9]{0,8}$/.test(value);
    });
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("nome", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9._ -]{4,16}$/.test(value);
    });
    $().ready(function() {
        var validator = $("#form3").bind("invalid-form.validate", function() {
            $("#summary").html("O formulário contém " + validator.numberOfInvalids() + " erros.");
        }).validate({
            debug: true,
            errorElement: "em",
            errorContainer: $("#warning, #summary"),
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.appendTo(element.parent("td").next("td"));
            },
            success: function(label) {
                label.text("").addClass("success");
            },
            rules: {
                steamid: {
                    required: true,
                    steam_id: true
                },
                username: {
                    required: true,
                    nome: true
                },
                nickname: {
                    required: true,
                    nome: true
                },
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Well, my question is, how do I submit this form to php. I want to insert a thing in a databse and I have a phpscript for that, but with this validation I can't do that.

Can you tell me how submit using jquery?

---

I'm using the jquery validation plugin from bassitance

Comment: 1: You ask how to submit that form, but all you are showing us is JavaScript:
2: This isn't a PHP related problem. It's JavaScript.

Comment: but I have the working php script, the only thing that is missing is how do I submit the form using jquery to php

you're right, this isn't php issue, sorry

Comment: submit it with a submit button?... silly suggestion from me but really I did not get you....

Comment: What validation plugin are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
debug: true,
```

When you have the [`debug` property](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) set to `true`, it actively prevents form submission...for debugging, so you can test your validation rules but never trigger a postback.  It's *purely* for testing.  Once you've got validation how you want it and you want to move to actually submitting the form (where you're at!), remove the `debug` setting (or set it to `false`).

As a side note, `$().ready(function() {` is deprecated in jQuery 1.4+, instead you should use one of these:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//or:
$(function() {
```

Answer (score -2):

You can submit a form using jQuery by calling .submit();

**Example:** $("#form3").submit();

**Reference:** http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: It doesnt work for me, when I put that the Ok images appear and doesnt't do anything, can you help me?


thanks!